# Howto inject a class into an already injected class (annotated with @Inject) within a Presenter in AfterburnerFX

Tags: java, javafx, dependency-injection

### Intro

Within the AfterburnerFX framework I have a CheckoutPresenter which has the object `printManager` injected to it. But since I would like to make use of stringConverter objects to aid me in designing physicial printouts, I need a way to inject these other objects into the simple POJO `printManager` object.

### Issue

I know that @Inject annoations can only happen within the Presenter Class with AfterburnerFX, but is there a way to make this happen? Moreover I don't really want to use static helper classes if possible.

```
public class CheckoutPresenter implements Initializable {

    @Inject
    private PrintManager printManager;
    ...
}
```

...

```
public class PrintManager {

// this is a standard POJO, not associated to AfterburnerFX framework
// need to have helper classes below injected 
    @Inject
    private QtyStringConverter qtyConv;
    @Inject
    private CurrencyStringConverter currConv;
}
```

Comment: *"I know that `@Inject` annotations can only happen within the Presenter Class with AfterburnerFX"* This is not true: fields annotated `@Inject` will be injected for any object that afterburner.fx manages (this includes presenters, and any objects that are injected by afterburner.fx into other objects). So the code you wrote should work just fine. If `qtyConv` nad `currConv` are not getting injected, you presumably have problems elsewhere in your code: consider posting a [MCVE] if it's really not working.

Comment: alright, lemme try to build and test an MVP.

Comment: I wrote a quick test (with afterburner.fx 1.6.0) and it worked just fine.

Comment: I just tried a mvp and it really does work. Hmmm... I think I might have caught a bad info somewhere in the web. Thanks for investing time & energy to lead me through this issue.